# iOS: UITableViewRowAnimationFade not working properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I have the following lines of code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableViewData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // Step 1
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; // Step 2

        if (!queue_C5K) { // Step 3
            LockrNotificationDataKeeper *LLDK = 
             [[LockrNotificationDataKeeper alloc] initWithData:@"##deletion##" 
                                                  andIndexPath:(int)indexPath.row 
                                                       andType:@"dR" 
                                                      delegate:self];
            [queue_C5K addOperation:LLDK];
        }
    }
}
```

So I remove the selected `UITableViewCell` from the current `UITableView` data in Step 1. In Step 2, the `animation` should take place. In Step 3, the selected data is going to be removed from the `datasource` (plist). The callback of Step 3 will reload my `UITableView`.

The problem is, that only the last `UITableViewCell` removes with an animation. All upper `UITableViewCells` don't. So if I have 5 cells, the first 4 cells do not have any animation while deleting them.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The callback of Step 3 will reload my tableView.
```

Do you call `[tableView reloadData]` ?  After call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, during the fade animation time, if you call `reloadData`, fade animation will be covered then you can't any fade result. Because reloadData will not effect the last line which data already been removed, so the last line cell has the fade animation.